# How can I properly outcomment this PHP code?

Tags: php, comments

I have this code:

```
<?php do_action('twentytwelve_credits'); ?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url(__('http://wordpress.org/', 'twentytwelve')); ?>" 
   title="<?php esc_attr_e('Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentytwelve'); ?>"
><?php printf(__('Proudly powered by %s', 'twentytwelve'), 'WordPress'); ?></a>
```

How should I outcomment that?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    echo 'This is a test'; // This is a one-line c++ style comment
    /* This is a multi line comment
       yet another line of comment */
    echo 'This is yet another test';
    echo 'One Final Test'; # This is a one-line shell-style comment
?>
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want the comments to be propagated to the browser or not:

```
<?php 
/* This very interesting comment won't show in the content sent to the browser
 */
do_action( 'twentytwelve_credits' ); 
// or some end of line comment, not forwarded to the browser either
?>
<!--
But this one will
-->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<?php /*do_action( 'twentytwelve_credits' ); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
*/ ?>
```

But I generally delete or replace that entire block.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* multi-line quote */
```

For a single line quote just type a hash (`#`) or double slashes (`//`) before it.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to comment in PHP:

```
/* INFO */ for multiline comments
# INFO  for single-line comments
// INFO for single-line comments
```